# How to clone a DOM node and insert it into an iframe while maintaining the scroll values of all children

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Given some DOM node I'd like to clone the node (I currently do this with [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)) and maintain the values of all scrolls within the node when copied into an `iframe`.

I think that I could walk the entire DOM tree of the original node, determine the scroll position for each element (using `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`), save that to a map or some sort of meta-data property on the element, do the clone, add the clone to the `iframe,` then walk the entire new DOM tree again to re-apply the scrolls.

Is there a better way? Better in this case mostly means "not having to walk the entire DOM tree twice"

Additional context: I maintain [`react-to-print`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print) and am trying to solve [this bug](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/603).

Comment: Sorry, I might not be understanding, but from what I perceive, adding an element naturally results in layout shift. The contents around the element would change their position and end up at different coordinates. Also, the distance between elements around the newly inserted element will change, so what exactly do you mean by maintaining scroll position?

Comment: It's a good callout, and one that I'm not trying to solve here. I would say for this question, assume that the styles, page size, and positioning of the element have not changed; I want to make a perfect copy of the element into the iframe.